# Excel VBA : How to Skip a line if value not match

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have problem in Skip a specific Line command.

If Value comparison True do the line, then comparison false means skip the line and goto next line.

When I run the code, I get an error

> Object defined - Runtime error 1004

Kindly help me with this problem

```
 If Sheets("Group").Range("F:F" = "Numbers") Then 'Value comparison
    GoTo Numbers 'Current Call function
    Else: GoTo Text 'Next Call function
    End If

    Numbers:
    DoEvents
    Call Numbers 'If number based serial call it
    Text:
    DoEvents
    Call Text 'If Text based serial call it
```

My screenshot:

[image]

See my Full Macro

```
Sub Bass()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
DoEvents
Call Groupit 'Category All Serial


If Sheets("Group").Range("F:F" = "Numbers") Then
GoTo Numbers
Else: GoTo Text
End If

If Sheets("Group").Range("F:F" = "Text") Then
GoTo Text
Else: GoTo withK
End If

If Sheets("Group1").Range("E:E" = "*K*") Then
GoTo withK
Else: GoTo withoutK
End If

If Sheets("Group1").Range("E:E" <> "*K*") Then
GoTo withoutK
Else: GoTo Lastln
End If

'Bookmarks
Numbers:
DoEvents
Call Numbers 'If number based serial call it
Text:
DoEvents
Call Text 'If Text based serial call it
withK:
DoEvents
Call BothwithK 'If K based serial call it
withoutK:
DoEvents
Call BothwithoutK 'If not"K" based serial call it
Lastln:
DoEvents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range` property of `Sheet` object doesn't accept parameters like `"F:F" = "Numbers"`. If you want to filter values you can use [AutoFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter). While if you want to check for any occurrence of a value then you could use `If Not Sheets("Group").Range("F:F").Find(What:= "Numbers", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then `

Comment: I think you meant to tag @HTH

Comment: @HTH This Code work but automatically close the sheet

Comment: @baskar, no workbook closing stament is visbile in your shown code. I guess it's in some other sub/function to which the control is returned after `Sub Bass()` errors out due to what I already explained you

Comment: If you could explain what should happen when you write e.g. Call Numbers?

Comment: when call the function its first copy the column if "numbers" value match in group sheet. paste to new sheet, then expand the serial# by another submacro then  auto fill upto last, copy the result and paste the values to next column , finally all values copy to new sheet. that's it

Comment: if you not understand . then tell me i will send video demo .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forech loop with some select case statements.

```
Sub Bass()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
DoEvents

Dim rngF As Range: Set rngF = Range("F:F")
Dim rngE As Range: Set rngE = Range("E:E")
Dim countNumbers As Integer, countText As Integer, countWithK As Integer, countWithoutK As intteger
countNumbers = 0
countText = 0
countWithK = 0
countWithoutK = 0
For Each cell In rngF
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "Numbers"
            countNumbers = countNumbers + 1
        Case "Text"
            countText = countText + 1
        Case "*K*"
            countWithK = countWithK + 1
        Case Else
        ' SomethingElse
    End Select
Next cell

If countNumbers > 0 Then
    Call NumbersSub
End If

If countText > 0 Then
    Call TextSub
End If

If countWithK > 0 Then
    Call countWithK
End If

countWithK = 0

For Each cell In rngE
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "*K*"
            countWithK = countWithK + 1
        Case "*"
            countWithoutK = countWithoutK + 1
        Case Else
           'SomethingElse
    End Select
Next cell

If countWithK > 0 Then
    Call withK
End If
If countWithoutK > 0 Then
    Call withoutK
End If

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Sub NumbersSub()
MsgBox "Number found"
End Sub
Sub TextSub()
MsgBox "Text found"
End Sub
Sub withK()
MsgBox "Text with K found"
End Sub
Sub withoutK()
MsgBox "Text without K found"
End Sub
```

Comment: This code have compile Error see this image [link] https://ibb.co/jfWWz4B

Comment: The error is caused due some sub names are not yet defined in the project. I Have updated the code with some additional subs for testing purpose.

Comment: Its now working. But Msgbox popup comes every row process, So i ignore the lines. And added Submacro calls in last Sub's... Thanks for your Helpful Answer.....

Comment: I have problem in the mentioned answer . It Repeat the loop based input Row count. But i need to call the Each subfunction only one time

Comment: You could insert a counter in the select case statement instead for, while looping each column. If some of the cases are true, you could set the counter to add 1 every time there is a match. After the first loop is done, check if counter is above the 0, and if true, call the sub routines only once, and do that after each iteration of the column. I have updated the code to reflect that addition.